# If $\mathfrak{p}S^{-1}A$ is principal, $\mathfrak{p}$ is also principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain and $S$ be a multiplicatively closed set of A.
 
Take a minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $SpecA\verb│\│\{(0)\}$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap S=\emptyset$.

If $\mathfrak{p}S^{-1}A$ is principal, $\mathfrak{p}$ is also principal?

If not, is it true when $S=\{1,x,x^2,\cdots\}$ where $x\in A$ is a non-zero prime element?

Comment: The answer to the first question is no. Take $A$ to be a Dedekind domain, and $S = A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ (the complement of $\mathfrak{p}$). Then $S^{-1} A$ is a DVR and $\mathfrak{p} S^{-1} A$ is principal: a DVR is a local ring that is also a PID. There are plenty of Dedekind domains that are not PIDs, though: take $A = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\mathfrak{p} = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$. I think the answer to the second question is also no, but I don't have an example off the top of my head.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, the answer to the first is no. The answer to the second is yes, and is the main content of what is known as Nagata's theorem. Under the hypothesis, you can find $q\in P$ with $x$ not dividing $q$ and generating $S^{-1}P$. Then, show that $q$ in fact generates $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New, better answer which does things correctly:

The answer to part 1 is no, as mentioned in the comments: $A=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, $p=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, $S=A\setminus p$. This ring $A$ is of dimension one, so $p$ is both a minimal and maximal prime.

For part 2, the answer is yes. We use the assumption that $p\cap S=\emptyset$. Recall that the localization map $A\to S^{-1}A=A[1/x]$ is injective since $S$ contains no zero divisors.

Assume $p$ is not principal with a minimal set of generators $f_1,\cdots,f_n$, $n>1$, but $pA[1/x]$ is principal. Pick an element $q\in pA[1/x]\cap A$ which generates $pA[1/x]$ and isn't divisible by $x$. Then there are elements $y_1,\cdots,y_n \in A[1/x]\setminus \{0\}$ so that $y_iq=f_i$. At least one of these equations must have $y_i\notin A\subset A[1/x]$ as otherwise all the equations would be valid in $A$ and $q$ would be a generator of $p$. After multiplying through by a suitable power of $x$, we get the equation $y_i'q=f_ix^m$ where $y_1'\notin (x)$ and $m>0$. But this is a contradiction, as $y_i',q\in A\setminus (x)$ but $y_i'q\in(x)$.

Comment: Is it true when $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal in $SpecA\verb|\|\{(0)\}$?

Comment: @Loveup I've fixed it, I think.